# android - How to backup the data without using database even if the app closes

Tags: android

In my application i want to maintain data without using the local DB even if the application closes. For this i created one class in my app, in that i created static variables so we can access them anywhere in the app. But here some times data is gone i don't know why it's happen. this process is good or any better is there? Somewhere i read that Shared Preferences is useful but i don't know about that.please can anyone share your ideas.

```
public class AJ_Constant {

    //New Food Item
    public static String strEntrySavedFoodItem = "";
    public static String strReportsSavedFoodItem = "";
    public static ArrayList<String> arrFoodItems = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public class ReportsContentActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.reports_content, null);  
        setContentView(contentView); 
       AJ_Constant.arrFoodItems.add("Sample");      }}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html
you can save your data by creating shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values). there are samples how to use SharedPreferences

Comment: is it good process to maintain the data? Why my data is gone?

Comment: as far as I know this is the standard way to maintain data in android

Comment: you can visit [android dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) there are some additional possibilities how to store data

Comment: sharedprefs is key value based so you could use an id for your listitems but i think it's better to write the content of your arraylist to a file separated by a delimiter